# Why is it not possible to combine `...` and named arguments in Ruby 3?

Tags: ruby, named-parameters, positional-parameter, ruby-3

In Ruby 3, the new `...` syntax was introduced, allowing constructs like these:

```
def locked_run(...)
  lock
  run(...)
  unlock
end
```

This is documented here: https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.0.html

After this discussion (https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16378), it was decided to let positional arguments in as well:

```
  def block_section(name, ...)
    section(name, true, ...)
  end
```

However, the following still leads to a syntax error:

```
  def block_section(...)
    section(block_section: true, ...)
  end
```

Why are positional arguments allowed with `...` but named arguments are not?

Comment: This isn't **exactly** an answer to your question, but could you not specify `**options` as a method parameter here, and `**options.merge(block_section: true)` below?

Comment: This wouldn't work if your method is also potentially expecting to receive positional arguments, though.

Comment: In the linked discussion Matz also [explains](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16378#note-8) the reason for this decision, namely to support `send` and `method_missing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
section(block_section: true, ...)
```

This wouldn't be the correct syntax anyway. Looking at how Ruby does things, it expects named arguments (i.e., hash) to be the last arguments after the normal ones.

```
def section(a,b,c,d: false)
  puts "#{a} #{b} #{c} #{d}"
end

def old_style_block_section(*args)
  section(*args,d: true)
  
  #=> syntax error, unexpected *, expecting ')'
  section(d: true,*args)
end

section(1,2,3,d: true)
old_style_block_section(1,2,3)

#=> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
section(d: true,1,2,3)
```

So what you would need is this:

```
section(..., block_section: true)
```

However, this still doesn't work, as it hasn't been implemented as part of the Ruby language grammar for the new `...` currently.

If you want this, I'd suggest creating an issue (or emailing or something else) to request it.